# Making content more responsive in terms of height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, position

I am trying to make my page more responsive. As of now I have my site's logo and then two content lines under it. This text moves up and down like crazy on any different computer screen resolution and I want it to remain fixed in place in terms of being in the location on the screen I want it to be. Not actually `position: fixed`. How can I make these lines of code more responsive?

```
#homeTitle {
color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-top: 155px;
    font-size: 6em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #800000;
}
#homeTitlePart2 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 40px;
    /*padding-right: 220px;*/
        padding-right: 20%;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 2.5em;
        font-family: 'Oswald', Helvetica;
        font-weight: 300; // 700 and 300 also available
}
#homeTitlePart3 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: right;
    clear: both;
    padding: 10px, 10px, 10px, 10px;
        padding-right: 10%;
    font-size: 2.5em;
        font-family: 'Oswald', Helvetica;
        font-weight: 400; // 700 and 300 also available
}
```

I created a fiddle to show what it looks like now.

https://jsfiddle.net/6x9mz2d3/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using position?
As I am getting the idea what u need to do is,

```
.ttl-container{
position:relative;
margin-top: 155px;
max-height:600px;
border:1px solid red;
}
#homeTitlePart2, #homeTitlePart3{
position:absolute;
display:block;
font-size: 2.5vw;
right:0;
font-family: 'Oswald', Helvetica;
}
#homeTitle{
font-size: 6vw;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 2px 2px #800000;
}
#homeTitlePart2 {
padding-top: 40px;
right:20%;
top:100px;
font-weight: 300;
}
#homeTitlePart3 {
padding: 10px;
top:200px;
right: 10%;
font-weight: 400;
}
```

See if you can do it in this way. Please note **font-size:(n)VW** is not supported in all browser. If you do not want to use it, then add media screen for all viewport which matters to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use max height,max width to make your page more response.
to get more information [click here](http://entertainment7899.blogspot.com/search/label/html)